# Retrieving combo box value

Tags: php, combobox

I need some help here. I have some code below, and my question is, how to retrieve each combo value when selected? I really got confused about it. Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

This is the 1st combo box

```
<div class="select-form">
<form action="#" method="POST">
<label>Tipe</label> <select name="tipeku">
<?php
echo "<option value=0 selected>- Pilih Tipe -</option>";
$tipe=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tipe ORDER BY id_tipe ASC");
while($tipeb=mysql_fetch_array($tipe)){
echo "<option value=$tipeb[nama_tipe]>$tipeb[nama_tipe]</option>";
}?>
</select>
</form>
```

This is the 2nd combo box

```
<form class="clearfix" action="#" method="POST">
<label>Jenis</label>
<select name="jenisku">
<?php
echo "<option value=0 selected>- Pilih Jenis -</option>";
$jenis=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jenis ORDER BY id_jenis ASC");
while($jenisb=mysql_fetch_array($jenis)){
echo "<option value=$jenisb[nama_jenis]>$jenisb[nama_jenis]</option>";
}?>
</select>
</form>
```

This is the 3rd combo box

```
<form class="clearfix" action="#" method="POST">
<label>Merk</label>
<select name="merkku">
<?php
echo "<option value=0 selected>- Pilih Merk -</option>";
$merk=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategori ORDER BY id_kategori ASC");
while($katb=mysql_fetch_array($merk)){
echo "<option value=$katb[nama_kategori]>$katb[nama_kategori]</option>";
}?>
</select>
</form>
```

This is the 4th combo box

```
<form class="clearfix" action="#" method="POST">
<label>Tahun</label>
<select name="tahun">
<?php
echo "<option value=0 selected>- Pilih Tahun -</option>";
$thn=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tahun ORDER BY id_thn ASC");
while($thnb=mysql_fetch_array($thn)){
echo "<option value=$thnb[nama_thn]>$thnb[nama_thn]</option>";
}?>
</select>
</form>

<a href="search.php?<?php echo $_POST[tipeku];?>" class="search-btn">Cari</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `$_POST['tipeku']` etc. However, I'm not sure if `<form action='#'>` is valid , but might be.

Comment: You should use single quotes around your MySQL like so $thnb['nama_thn'] and using any mysql_* function is depreciate and removed from 5.5, you need to use PDO or whatever.

Comment: are your trying to post them via the last <a> tag?

Comment: I beg your pardon, I'm new to php & mysql, and still learning. I got those sample code from some pdf tutorials. By the way, I tried to use $_POST, but still I can't get the $_POST value. Also, if I tried to use a single quotes like $thb['nama_thn'] for example, the page thrown an error, but when I not using the single quotes, the page redirect properly, but without $_POST value. Oh yeah, believe me, it burns my eyes too...lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //check if form was submited
    {
        if(isset($_POST['tipeku']))
        {
            $tipeku = $_POST['tipeku']; //here you have the value of select box
            //save to database or do what you want to do
        }
    }
?>

<div class="select-form">
    <form action="" method="POST"> //make action = '' if want to post to the same page
    <label>Tipe</label> 
    <select name="tipeku">
    <?php
        echo "<option value='0' selected>- Pilih Tipe -</option>"; //use quotes around the value
        $tipe=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tipe ORDER BY id_tipe ASC");
        while($tipeb=mysql_fetch_array($tipe)){
        echo "<option value='".$tipeb['nama_tipe']."'>".$tipeb['nama_tipe']."</option>";
    }?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> <!--Provide submit button to submit the form-->
    </form>
</div>
```

This is for one select box. If you want to get the value of all select drop downs places all those inside the `<form></form>` tags and get them as i described above.